# Verify integrity of Struts download with Keys file

Tags: download, struts2, md5, sha1

I am trying to verify the integrity of the Struts download file as they recommend at [Verify Integrity](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#verify).  They say to download the Keys file from the [Main distribution directory](https://www.apache.org/dist/struts/2.3.32/) but I don't see anything titled keys.  Do they mean the md5 or sha1 files?

When I go to the `Main distribution directory` I see the following list.  Which one is the `KEYS` file?

[image]

Comment: The PGP signatures can be verified using PGP or GPG. First download the [KEYS](https://www.apache.org/dist/struts/KEYS) as well as the `asc` signature file for the particular distribution. Make sure you get these files from the [main distribution directory](https://www.apache.org/dist/struts/), rather than from a mirror.

Comment: The link attached to `KEYS` goes to a web page full of keys strung together.  Am I supposed to use one of those?  If so, which one?

Comment: Keep reading... `pgpk -a KEYS` `pgpv ${filename}.tar.gz.asc`

Comment: `pgpk -a KEYS` occurs after the `KEYS` file is download (i.e. `First download the KEYS` which is the part I don't know how to do.  I have downloaded Gpg4win to check the keys after I have them.

Comment: Right click -> `Save Link As...`

Comment: What program do I need to download to use the `pgpk` command per your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify integrity by downloading `.sha1` or `.md5` files that contain a hash. Then use some of the utilities (i.e. [`md5sum`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) or [`sha1sum`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum)) to verify downloaded files.